# Infinite recursion with the Rand monad

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

I have this working program:

```
import Control.Monad.Random

data Tree = Node Tree Tree Tree Tree
          | Leaf Bool
          deriving (Show)

randomTree' :: (RandomGen a) => Int -> Rand a Tree
randomTree' 0 = do
  r <- getRandom
  return $ Leaf r

randomTree' depth = do
  let d = depth-1
  a <- randomTree' d
  b <- randomTree' d
  c <- randomTree' d
  d <- randomTree' d
  r <- getRandom
  if r
    then return $ Node a b c d
    else randomTree' 0

randomTree1 :: Int -> Tree
randomTree1 seed = evalRand (randomTree' 4) (mkStdGen seed)

main = print $ randomTree1 1
```

But I don't fully understand why this other version fails and fills up all my RAM (with thunks ?):

```
randomTree'' :: (RandomGen a) => Int -> Rand a Tree
randomTree'' depth = do
  let d = depth-1
  a <- randomTree'' d
  b <- randomTree'' d
  c <- randomTree'' d
  d <- randomTree'' d

  r1 <- getRandom
  r2 <- getRandom
  if depth > 0 && r1
    then return $ Node a b c d
    else return $ Leaf r2
```

Thanks to laziness, shouldn't `a` `b` `c` and `d` be evaluated only if needed ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using same name for different variables, something is wrong...

Comment: I'd move the recursive calls under the `then` branch, so that you only make them when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, laziness can't help you here: the random seed being threaded through the computation adds a data dependency that negates any possible laziness.

Specifically: you check whether `r1`, computed from a call to `getRandom`, is `True`. To know that, one must discover which seed to use when calling `getRandom`; and to know which seed to use, one must first do the modifications to the seed that are demanded by the recursive calls to `randomTree''`. Since the recursive calls never bottom out in a base case, they just chew up more and more RAM until your computer chokes. Bummer!

Comment: *But* random generators support `split` which does allow you to create a lazy random "monad" (the monad laws will not hold exactly, but if all you care about is the distribution of values then they do)

Comment: @luqui is this [Control.Monad.Random.Lazy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Lazy.html) ?

Comment: @TimothéeJourde No, that module still appears to keep the data dependence on seeds in its `Monad`'s `(>>=)` implementation.